# Linq - In memory join vs EF Join

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, join

Using EF 6 and SQL 2014.

Assuming you have a well indexed and normalized DB. Is it 'better' to pull entities into memory then perform the join on the IEnumerables or let EF do join via IQueryable?

By better -> faster execution time, less reads on DB, Mem usage.

**Example in memory:**

```
using (var context = myDbContext())
{
    var table1 = await context.Table1.ToListAsync();
    var table2 = await context.Table2.ToListAsync();
    var table3 = await context.Table3.ToListAsync();

    var resultSet = table1
        .Join(table2, t1 => t1.Id, t2 => t2.Table1Id, (t1,t2) => new {t1, t2})
        .Join(table3, x => x.t2.Table2Id, t3 => t3.Table2Id, (x, t3) => new { x.t1, x.t2, t3})
        .ToList();
}
```

**Example EF:**

```
using (var context = myDbContext())
{
    var resultSet = await context.Table1
        .Join(context.Table2, t1 => t1.Id, t2 => t2.Table1Id, (t1,t2) => new {t1, t2})
        .Join(context.Table3, x => x.t2.Table2Id, t3 => t3.Table2Id, (x, t3) => new { x.t1, x.t2, t3})
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: “faster execution time” is pretty easy to measure

Comment: use StopWatch to measure execution time. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I think the notion of using `IQueryable<T>` and expressions as more along the lines of evaluating the expression tree (or the intention itself) and determining/optimizing it.  think of it like a SQL QueryOptimizer in that you put an expression tree forward, and the tree is optimized/reduced to a better expression.  so this one method scope representation isn't really suitable to that, because it isn't complex.

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Comment: Some suggested to measure execution time. This is fairly difficult on a DBMS. It depends too much  on others performing queries and recent queries. If recently a temporary table was created for some query and another query needs the same result, this table is re-used by a smart DBMS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you know if one car is faster than another? Drive both of them and compare the times.

*Generally*, databases are more efficient at joining data than in-memory Linq (due to pre-computed indices, hashes, etc.) but there certainly could be cases where in-memory would be faster.  However, when you're not pulling ALL of the data into memory, the benefit of having *less data over the wire* might make a bigger difference than any performance improvement in joining.

So there's not a definitive answer. Start with something that *works*, THEN focus on performance improvements by measuring the time before and after the changes.

Comment: If you're testing how fast a car is and you test it during peak hour traffic on the commute home from work it won't really matter how fast the car can actually go. It's all about the traffic then.

Answer (score 0):

One of the slower parts of executing a database query is the transport of the data from the DBMS to your local process. Hence it is wise to limit the amount of data to be transported to your process. Only transport the data you actually plan to use.

So if you query "Teachers with their Students", you'll know that the ID of the teacher will equal the foreign key 'TeacherId`in every`Student`. So why transport this foreign key for every of the teacher's 1000 students if you already know the value?

Another reason to let the DBMS perform the query is because the software in the database is optimized to perform queries. If the DBMS created a temporary table for a query, and it detects that a new query needs the same temporary table, a smart DBMS will reuse this temporary table, even if the query came from another process.

Smart DBMSes will  detect that certain indexes are used more often than others, and keep them in memory, instead of reading them from disk all the time.

So a DBMS has all kinds of tricks to speed up the execution of queries.

You can see that this tricks help by measuring: perform a query twice in a row and see that the second query is executed faster than the first one. This effect is also a reason that **you can't measure whether it is faster to let given query execute by the DBMS or to execute it in local memory.**, as some suggested.

The only proper method would be to measure the chosen strategy with all kinds of queries during a longer period of time (minutes, if not hours), with a lot of processes that perform these queries. One thing you'll know for certain is that executing queries AsEnumerable can't benefit from the queries executed by others.